Can i check the timestamp of last execution of scheduled task?
Can i check the timestamp of last execution of scheduled task. I have the Scheduled task which is scheduled every hour. But before running the task every time i want to see when did this task ran last time and depending on that either run or halt the new run. Is this achievable ? I am using spring boot scheduler right now .
